# UIRefreshControl lagging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableview which contains users' posts. Each post has a picture, username, and the post itself. The refresh control's action is to reload the table with data from Parse. Everything works perfectly except for the extreme lag when I pull to refresh. I don't know if it's because of the pictures in each cell or something else. If anyone has an idea of why this would happen please let me know. I will post the code if anyone needs it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3878 green:0.5686 blue:1.0 alpha:0.9];
[userPostsTable addSubview:refreshControl];

}


-(void) retrieveFromParse {

PFQuery *quoteQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Quotes"];
quoteQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[quoteQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[quoteQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSString *category = [object objectForKey:@"Category"];

        if (category == nil) {

            quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Light Italic" size:15];

        }

        else {

            quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15];

        }

        quoteString = [object objectForKey:@"quoteContent"];
        quoteLabel.text = quoteString;

        quoteIdString = object.objectId;
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];


    }

    else {

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}];

PFQuery *userPostsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"userPosts"];
userPostsQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[userPostsQuery setLimit:300];
[userPostsQuery whereKey:@"quoteObjectId" matchesKey:@"objectId" inQuery:quoteQuery];
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    [userPostsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

}
else {

[userPostsQuery orderByDescending:@"likeCount"];

}
[userPostsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        userPostsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [userPostsTable reloadData];
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];

    }

    else {

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}];


}
```

Comment: Without code, can't say anything.

Comment: Is the code inside the completion block called on the main thread or a background thread? That could be the issue, although I'm not familiar with parse too much and their documentation doesn't say if its called on the main thread or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving the objects in background thread.

```
getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:
```

Also you are trying to update your UI from background thread. You need to update UI from main thread only:

Call all UI related calls like:

```
[userPostsTable reloadData];
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

From main thread only.

Use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // Update UI
});
```

Comment: I tried that out and it did not make the refresh any smoother.

Comment: @bpomp87: Can you remove the code from that method and can you check whether there is any lag ? Also is there any other code in those methods ? Did you made all `[refreshControl endRefreshing];` inside dispatch_async ?

Comment: If I make the refresh control's action something other than the retrieveFromParse method, then there is no lag. There is no other code in those methods. And yes, I made all of the [refreshControl endRefreshing]; inside dispatch_async.

Comment: @bpomp87: Can you write whole code in the method inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ });` and let me know the result

Comment: That did not solve the issue. Do you think it has something to do with the images in each cell? I have another tableview in the app containing no images. It has a refresh control with a retrieveFromParse method. It does not lag at all.

Comment: @bpomp87: You are not loading images when the tableView is refreshing or scrolling right ? If no, then it'll be the reason.

Comment: Well when it refreshes, the method updates the objects array from parse and reloads the table. So none of the existing posts in the table are changing. Only new ones are added (if there is any).

Comment: @bpomp87: I'm not familiar with parse, so don't know about that. One more thing, you are refreshing whole table using: `[userPostsTable reloadData];`. Also only call this method after `[refreshControl endRefreshing];`. Sorry that, I couldn't help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code snippets are part of a `UITableViewController`, you should not be adding the `refreshControl` as a `subview` of the `tableView`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse)                  
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3878 green:0.5686 blue:1.0 alpha:0.9];

    //This is causing the stutter
    //[userPostsTable addSubview:refreshControl];
    //UIRefreshControl is meant to be used by a UITableViewController
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I have added it to other table views before and it has worked just fine.